# rsync failed: No Such file or directory

Tags: windows, backup, samba, rsync

I'm using rsync in Windows ( through `cygwin64` ) to backup some data to an samba share. I've made this bat file that would take care of everything:

```
net use S: \\10.1.1.23\marc password /user:marc

rsync -rtvu --delete /cygdrive/d/Backup/ /cygdrive/s/sync/Backup/
rsync -rtvu --delete /cygdrive/d/Marc/programmeren/ /cygdrive/s/sync/Marc/programmeren/
rsync -rtvu --delete /cygdrive/d/Marc/School/ /cygdrive/s/sync/Marc/School/
rsync -rtvu --delete /cygdrive/d/Marc/Werk/ /cygdrive/s/sync/Marc/Werk/
rsync -rtvu --delete /cygdrive/d/Marc/Thuis/docs/ /cygdrive/s/sync/Marc/Thuis/docs/

pause
net use S: /delete
pause
```

The first `rsync` command runs fine, but after that one i only get errors. Here's the output i get:

```
C:\Users\Marc\Desktop>rsync -rtvu --delete /cygdrive/d/Backup/ /cygdrive/s/sync/
Backup/
sending incremental file list
created directory /cygdrive/s/sync/Backup
./
Mail/
Mail/Thunderbird 24.5.0 (nl) - 2014-05-09.pcv

sent 76601561 bytes  received 38 bytes  6661008.61 bytes/sec
total size is 76592063  speedup is 1.00

C:\Users\Marc\Desktop>rsync -rtvu --delete /cygdrive/d/Marc/programmeren/ /cygdr
ive/s/sync/Marc/programmeren/
sending incremental file list
rsync: mkdir "/cygdrive/s/sync/Marc/programmeren" failed: No such file or direct
ory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /usr/src/ports/rsync/rsync-3.0.9-1/sr
c/rsync-3.0.9/main.c(587) [Receiver=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /usr/src/ports/rsy
nc/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]

C:\Users\Marc\Desktop>rsync -rtvu --delete /cygdrive/d/Marc/School/ /cygdrive/s/
sync/Marc/School/
sending incremental file list
rsync: mkdir "/cygdrive/s/sync/Marc/School" failed: No such file or directory (2
)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /usr/src/ports/rsync/rsync-3.0.9-1/sr
c/rsync-3.0.9/main.c(587) [Receiver=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /usr/src/ports/rsy
nc/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]

C:\Users\Marc\Desktop>rsync -rtvu --delete /cygdrive/d/Marc/Werk/ /cygdrive/s/sy
nc/Marc/Werk/
sending incremental file list
rsync: mkdir "/cygdrive/s/sync/Marc/Werk" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /usr/src/ports/rsync/rsync-3.0.9-1/sr
c/rsync-3.0.9/main.c(587) [Receiver=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /usr/src/ports/rsy
nc/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]

C:\Users\Marc\Desktop>rsync -rtvu --delete /cygdrive/d/Marc/Thuis/docs/ /cygdriv
e/s/sync/Marc/Thuis/docs/
sending incremental file list
rsync: mkdir "/cygdrive/s/sync/Marc/Thuis/docs" failed: No such file or director
y (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /usr/src/ports/rsync/rsync-3.0.9-1/sr
c/rsync-3.0.9/main.c(587) [Receiver=3.0.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (9 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /usr/src/ports/rsy
nc/rsync-3.0.9-1/src/rsync-3.0.9/io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]
```

Can somebody please explain to me why this isn't working? I already `chmod 777 -R` on `/home/marc/` but that didn't work either...

My rsync version: `version 3.0.9 protocol version 30`

-btw-, i'm not using SSH, because i'm using it inside my home network

**-Working-**

Alright, I've got it working now. I've manually created the root directory's ( `marc/programmeren, marc/school, marc/...` and now it's working.

So do you guys know any better way to handle that exception? ( that RSync will manualy create those folders if there not created yet...)